# How to replace a word in a file by a word get by read function?

Tags: bash, sed, replace

Situation:

```
echo "tell me a word"
read the_word
```

How to replace all WordToReplace in a file by the_word?

sed does not seems to appreciate:

```
sed -i 's/WordToReplace/$the_word/g' thefile.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are not expanded within single quotes, they are treated literally then.

Use double quotes instead:

```
sed -i "s/WordToReplace/$the_word/g" thefile.sh
```